# Trying to formate DateTime? variable causes "No overload for method ToString takes 1 argument error"

Tags: c#, datetime

I am building out a `ViewModel` and in it I am trying to format a `DateTime` in `MMMM dd, yyyy` format but it is throwing the error

```
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument
```

I used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx to come up with the code

`DateUpdated.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`

but that is apparently wrong. What is the correct way to format the date?

ViewModel:

```
public class ConversionFactorsVM
{
    [Required]
    public int TankID { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true), DisplayName("Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true), DisplayName("Product ID")]
    public int Productnumber { get; set; }

    [Required, Range(0, 200.9, ErrorMessage = "Gravity must be between 0 and 200.9")]
    public decimal Gravity { get; set; }

    [Required, Range(0, 200.9, ErrorMessage = "Temperature must be between 0 and 200.9")]
    public decimal Temperature { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public decimal Factor { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Updated")]
    public string LastUpdate
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateUpdated.HasValue)
            {
                return DateUpdated.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
            }
            else
            {
                return "Never Updated.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use [`Nullable<DateTime>.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since that's the `DateTime`:

```
return DateUpdated.Value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Will mark as answer once SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) propery for getting the value of `Nullable<DateTime>`

> Gets the value of the current `Nullable<T>` object if it has been
>   assigned a valid underlying value.

Here an example in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net);

```
DateTime? DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
DateUpdated.Value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy").Dump();
```

Output will be;

```
January 14, 2014
```